# Ubuntu 12.04 upgrade php 5.4 missing php5-ffmpeg

Tags: php, php5, ffmpeg

I updated php to version 5.4, through the repository ppa:ondrej/php5, but now I can not install the package php5-ffmpeg because it gives me this error: php5-ffmpeg: Depends: phpapi-20090626

also if I try to write php-v gives me this warning:

```
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
'/usr/lib/php5/20100525/ffmpeg.so' - / usr/lib/php5/20100525/ffmpeg.so:
can not open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
5.4.17RC1 PHP (cli) (built: Jun 22 2013 19:27:26)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

Some solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you start installing packages outside of the core Ubuntu repositories, you sacrifice any guarantees of compatibility.

This ppa maintainer didn't create this package in a way that says that it provides `phpapi-20090626`, even if it actually does.  Hence, any package that depends on `phpapi-20090626` will not be installed.

Your options at this point are to:

1. Find a ppa of php5-ffmpeg that doesn't require any packages you don't currently have installed.
2. Compile and package your own version of php5-ffmpeg that doesn't require `phpapi-20090626`.
3. Compile and package your own version of php5.4 so that it claims to provide `phpapi-20090626` and then install the normal php5-ffmpeg.
4. Roll back to standard core Ubuntu repositories for all packages.